# How to convert a string to JSON?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm using volley to get a file from the internet, the file is an array. I'm saving the file in cache to do this I have to convert the file into a string. I have a function that reads the cache and pass the response to another file to display
the information, but when i'm trying to convert the resoionse back to an array i get an error

```
Value AuthStatus of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I'm really new on android, hoping someone can point me on the right direction

```
private void cacheFile(JSONObject response) {
     JSONObject res  = response;
     String filename = "jsonfile";
     FileOutputStream outputStream;

     try {
         outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         outputStream.write(res.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
         outputStream.close();
         Log.e(TAG, "Bien");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

private void readCache(String filename) {
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
        inputStream.read();
        String body = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        inputStream.close(); 
        fromCache(body);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void fromCache(String json) { 

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cars");
        Log.e(TAG, "Array Size: " + jsonArray.length());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSONValue.parse method as shown below:

```
public void fromCache(String json) { 
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cars");
        Log.e(TAG, "Array Size: " + jsonArray.length());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea why android studio dont recognize JSONValue